# How to configure LibreOffice Impress to be able to click on the shape behind an another concave shape?

Tags: shapes, libreoffice-impress

I have a problem of not being able to click on the shapes which are seen via a concave part of another shape. Here is a screenshot of a running presentation -- these are three bookmarks which are set to be pulled out to the right when clicked on each one of them:
[image: A running presentation with clickable bookmarks, which are dragged right when clicked]

But when I click on the red or blue bookmark, only the orange one responds:
[image]

It is arranged on top of all others, yes, but it is defined as a combined shape, and when editing presentation you can clearly see that its points are not covering the blue and red bookmarks:
[image]

Has anybody encountered similar problem and know how to resolve it? Thanks